# Understanding ArgMin with constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization, piecewise

Consider this simple snippet:

```
ArgMin[{(x - a)^2, -1 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

which should (in my mind) output something like

$$
x = \begin{cases}
-1 & a < -1 \\
a & -1 \leq a \leq 1 \\
1 & 1 < a
\end{cases}
$$

but instead outputs

$$
\begin{cases}
-1 & a = -1 \\
a & -1 < a \leq 1 \\
a - \sqrt{(a-1)^2} & a > 1 \\
a + \sqrt{(a+1)^2} & \text{True}
\end{cases}
$$

Can somebody explain this "strange" result?  Should I perhaps phrase the constraints differently?

Comment: thanks for the latex fix @Henrik Schumacher. I suppose it requires moderator priviliges of some sort?

Comment: You're welcome. Not a problem, you can do it yourself.  Just don't mark $\LaTeX$-code as code (no indentation).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher doesn't appear to be working, even if i try to edit without making any changes, it won't let me save it due to said error.

Comment: Towards your actual question: The result comes indeed somewhat surprising, but it is correct. You can simplify it by `Simplify[ex, a \[Element] Reals]`. Maybe `ArgMin`  writes down the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions internally and solves them with `Reduce`? In that case, Mathematica might skip the `Simplify` in order to make it work in reasonable time. KKT conditions become easily very complicated and `Simplify` might take forever.

Comment: Towards $\LaTeX$: That's indeed weird. I never had this problem but I recall that users complained about not being able to post code. Maybe it is indeed linked to lack of reputation...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher the KKT theory is indeed an interesting one. I was looking into this because I have a nested optimization problem, which takes forever to solve. I think it may be because the output is NOT simplified and the "strange" terms carry over from one optimization to the next.

Comment: Yes, that may happen with symbolic computations. This why I would try to retreat to numerical optimization as soon as possible...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Simplifying the output of my "nested" optimizations in fact solved the problem! I will consider moving to numerical optimization but since I have many parameters, which I would have to assume values for (and consequently consider all cases manually), I'd like to stick to symbolic as long as possible